# Batch download with two ranges with wget

Tags: curl, download, wget

I have got a PHP image gallery, which has about 20000 photo files. I want to backup the images on my own server, but here is my problem with the url;

```
http://photos.blabla.net/photo.php?g=XX&p=YY
```

XX is gallery number, and YY is photo number. The photos can't be accessed with a wrong gallery number provided. So I want to create a batch download, eg.;

```
http://photos.blabla.net/photo.php?g=[1:2000]&p=[1:20000]
```

How can I accomplish this with wget or curl or any other way in a shell account. Or even any Windows workaround will be appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can not accomplish this with `wget` alone.

Running it as a subprocess in a couple lines of Python does the trick (in theory):

```py
import subprocess

g=1
p=1

while g <= 2000:
    while p <= 20000:
        subprocess.Popen(['wget', '-A jpg', 'http://photos.blabla.net/photo.php?g='+g+'&p='+p+''])
        p = p+1
    g = g+1
    p = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Python script is always nice. But if you do not want to write an extra script, use one-line command in bash:

```
for g in {1..2000}; do for p in {1..20000}; do wget http://photos.blabla.net/photo.php?g=$g&p=$p; done done
```